# Add TextField to UIAlertView in Swift that saves to a TableView controller

Tags: ios, swift

**Edit:**  Thank you for the replies, yes I needed an alert and not an action sheet!  I have implemented this new code and it works, but is there a reason why it segues to the next view before the user can enter a ride title?

Also it throws this message in the debug console, should I be concerned?

> 2016-02-16 12:30:21.675 CartoBike[687:128666] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged .

```
@IBAction func stopAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ride Stopped", message: "Give a title to your ride", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default,
        handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            // Allow for text to be added and appended into the RideTableViewController
            let textField = alert.textFields!.first
            rideContent.append(textField!.text!)

    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
        style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField: UITextField) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Save the ride
    saveRide()

    // Automatically segue to the Ride details page
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowRideDetail", sender: nil)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    timer.invalidate()

    self.stopLocation()
}
```

**Overview:** 
I am working my way through my first real app.  The basic logic is a home screen to start a new ride or view previous rides.  Starting a ride will open a new view with a map to record a bicycle ride based on the users location, this can be stopped and save the ride and immediately switch to a new view to see a map of the ride. Alternatively from the home screen the user can select previous rides and view a list of their old rides in a table view and select one and transition to a detailed view with a map of their ride.

**Problem:**  When adding a `UIAlertAction` I would like there to be a *save* and *cancel* feature. In addition, I would like the user to be able to add a custom title by typing it in via a text field.  The input from the text field will be appended to a global variable called rideContent that is tied to the creation of new cells in the table view to store multiple bike rides by unique title.

**Research:**
I have reviewed the questions titled "How to add a `TextField` to `UIAlertView` in Swift" & "Writing handler for `UIAlertAction`" and still can't seem to discern what I have done wrong.  Ideally the alert within this screenshot of an [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1gSR.png) from the raywenderlich site is what I would like it to look like. I am not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible since there a so many view controllers involved. Granted I am new to swift and I'm sure I am missing something obvious!

Currently getting an error of

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context", see screenshot: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kac6a.png)

**Here is the UIAlertController code:**

```
// The timer pauses & the location stops updating when the the stop button is pressed
@IBAction func stopAction(sender: UIButton) {

    var inputTextField: UITextField?

    let actionSheetController = UIAlertController (title: "Ride Stopped", message: "Add a title to your ride", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    // Add a cancel action
    actionSheetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

    // Add a save action
    actionSheetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        (actionSheetController) -> Void in


    //Add a text field  --- Getting an error on this line
    actionSheetController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
        // you can use this text field
        inputTextField = textField

        // Append the ride title to the table view
        rideContent.append(textField!.text!)

        // Update when user saves a new ride to store the ride in the table view for permanent storage
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(rideContent, forKey: "rideContent")


        // Save the ride
        self.saveRide()

        // Automatically segue to the Ride details page
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowRideDetail", sender: nil)
        }}))

        //present actionSheetController
        presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        timer.invalidate()

        self.stopLocation()

    }
```

Thank you stack overflow for any help you may offer!

Comment: Pretty sure you need a controller of type alert and not of type action sheet to add text fields.

Comment: Thank you @pbush25!  I switched my code to an alert and not action sheet, any idea why it throws this message in the console? "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged"

Comment: can you update your code please?

Comment: @pbush25 An edit explanation and new code should be at the top of the post! Should I delete the old code?

Comment: Well I think your question is answered pretty clearly.... You call perform segue before you present the alert!

Comment: @pbush25 Excellent, yes I see now what I was doing wrong. I'm always learning something new!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an .ActionSheet while the tutorial you showed is using an .Alert

Action Sheets can have buttons but not text fields.

"Alerts can have both buttons and text fields, while action sheets only support buttons."

[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/)

Comment: Thank you! I switched my code to an alert and not action sheet.  Do you have any idea why it throws this message in the console? "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged" Should I be worried?

Comment: Are you showing the alert when the app first opens? If so, that would cause the warning you're getting in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Use your tableview Array when Add Button is pressed and "Add alertview textfirld to tableview array and then reload tableview".

```
@IBAction func btnAdd(_ sender: Any) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Category", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default, handler: { alert -> Void in
        let firstTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
        self.categories.add(firstTextField.text!)
        self.tblCatetgory.reloadData()
    })
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {
        (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in })
    alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Category!!!"
    }

    alertController.addAction(saveAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}